# Why can't we resize partition without using Live USB/CD just like in windows?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

We are able to partition in windows even after login in to it without using Live USB/CD. But in ubuntu its quite complex task. We need to have a Live USB/CD of ubuntu or GParted to be able to resize the partition. isn't there a gap ? isn't there a possibility to improve this ?

is there any way that can be done without Live CD/USB ?

Comment: "We are able to partition in windows even after login in to it" Oh? Try shrinking your C: drive to eliminate most of the available free space.

Comment: @muru See answer...  **;-)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any partition that is in use cannot be resized *on any operating system*:

- On Ubuntu you can unmount any partition and resize it except the partition mounted to `/` (although you can still resize the *filesystem* on `/` to make it *larger*..)
- On Windows you can do the same except `%windir%` (Usually `C:`)

*However*, on Ubuntu, you can even resize `/` with *an Ubuntu Live USB/DVD* whereas on Windows, you need to:

- buy external tools
- ***use the Ubuntu Live CD/DVD to resize the Windows system drive!***

## :-)

Comment: Turns out, you can also resize the *filesystem* mounted on `/` **live** if you're making it larger. Resizing the partition is a different story, though.

Comment: @muru :D :D :D [Crossed the T's](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1078526/revisions) (not dotting the Is and mentioning LVM)  **;-)**